# Continuous function $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I have a function $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow [c,d]$ that is bijective and monotonic increasing. I have to show that $f$ is also a continuous function. I wanted to show this by contradiction that for $f$ is not a continuous function it cannot be bijective or monotone increasing, but unfortunately I didn't get a suitable result. Can someone give me a hint how to do this prove, please?

Comment: In every point left and right limits exists because of the monotonicity. They must be equal because $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @Jochen how surjective is used to show that left hand limit is equal to right hand limit???

Comment: @SR23 If you take $\alpha$ strictly between the left-hand and the right-hand limit at some point $x_0$, then $\alpha$ should be $f(x)$ for some $x$. But no $x$ can do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m \in (a,b)$ be arbitrary, then we use that $f$ is continuous at the point $m$ if and only if $\lim_{x \uparrow m} f(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow m} f(x),$ where both expressions exist. If you are at either $m=a$ or $m=b$ you only have to consider the respective one-sided limit, so it is even easier there.

To prove this, we will show that $\lim_{x \uparrow m} f(x) = \sup_{x< m} f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \downarrow m} f(x) = \inf_{x>m}f(x)$ (note that the inf and sup always exist, so this settles the question of existence.)

To show that something is the supremum we have to show that it is the smallest upper bound and similarly for the infimum.

Clearly,$ \forall x < m: f(x) \le \sup_{x< m} f(x)$ by the definition of the sup and also $\forall x>m : f(x) \ge \inf_{x> m}f(x).$

And since $f$ is increasing we have even more:
$$\forall x < m: f(x) \le \sup_{x< m} f(x) \le f(m)$$ and

$$\forall x>m : f(x) \ge \inf_{x> m}f(x) \ge f(m).$$

Now, let $x_n$ be an arbitrary increasing sequence $x_n \uparrow m$ and $y_n$ be an arbitrary decreasing sequence $y_n \downarrow m.$

Then we have since $f$ is increasing from what we said previously that $f(x_n )\le \sup_{x< m} f(x)$ and $\inf_{x> m}f(x)\le f(y_n).$ So $f(x_n)$ is a sequence that is bounded from above by $\sup_{x< m} f(x)$ and increasing as $f$ is increasing. Such a sequence does always converge (this is a theorem probably from your lecture). The same is true for $f(y_n)$ since it is decreasing (as $y_n$ is a decreasing sequence and $f$ is increasing) and bounded from below.

Now what are the limits? Let $x<m$ be arbitrary then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)\ge f(x)$ since $f$ is increasing, i.e. $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall n>n_0: x_n>x \Rightarrow f(x_n) \ge f(x)$, from which we see that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \ge f(x).$

So we have shown that $\forall x<m: f(x) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \le \sup_{x<m} f(x),$ i.e. \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) is an upper-bound for $\{f(x); x<m\}$ and is also the smallest one as it is smaller than the supremum.

Thus, we must have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)= \sup_{x<m} f(x).$ Since $(x_n)$ was an arbitrary increasing sequence, we have $\lim_{x \uparrow m}f(x) = \sup_{x<m} f(x).$
The same argument shows $\lim_{x \downarrow m}f(x)=\inf_{x>m} f(x).$

Hence, we have

$$\lim_{x \uparrow m} f(x)=\sup_{x<m} f(x) \le f(m) \le \inf_{x >m} f(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow m}.$$

Now the question is: Do we have equality in the two inequalities?

Assume that either one inequality is strict, wlog $f(m)< \inf_{x >m} f(x)$. Then $\exists w: f(m)< w<\inf_{x >m} f(x).$ Since $f$ is bijective we have $q\in [a,b]$ such that $w=f(q).$ Since $f$ is increasing we must have $m<q$ as $f(m)<w=f(q).$ On the other hand, we always have that $\inf_{x>m}f(x)\le f(q)$ as from what we just said $m<q$, but this is a contradiction to $f(m)< w<\inf_{x >m} f(x).$ . This shows that $f(m) = \lim_{x \downarrow m}$. The same argument shows that the other inequality is actually an equality.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $f$ is discontinuous at some point, let's say $m \in [a,b]$, then $\lim_{x\to m}f(x) \neq f(m)$ by definition.  Notice that if the left-hand limit and right-hand limit at $m$ are equal, then $f(m)$ cannot be larger or smaller than the limit, as that would break monotonicity.  Therefore, intuitively, the left-hand limit must be strictly less than the right-hand limit, $\lim_{x\to m^-}f(x) < \lim_{x\to m^-}f(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to m^-}f(x) \leq f(m) \leq \lim_{x\to m^-}f(x)$.  Then if there's a point $f(z) \in [c,d]$ such that $\lim_{x\to m^-}f(x) < f(z) < \lim_{x\to m^-}f(x)$ and $f(z)\neq f(m)$, there is no point $z\in [a,b]$ that satisfies $f(z)$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $f$ is surjective.  Therefore, $f$ must be continuous.